# C - Посимвольная обработка строки в цикле

Tags: c, массивы, строки

На днях делал здесь данную задачу :

Даны символы s1,s2,... Известно, что символ s1 отличен от пробела и что среди s2,s3,... имеется хотя бы один пробел. Рассматриваются s1,...,sn - символы, предшествующие первому пробелу (n заранее неизвестно). Преобразовать последовательность s1,..., sn, удалив из каждой группы идущих подряд цифр, в которой более двух цифр и которой предшествует точка, все цифры, начиная с третьей (например, ab+0.1973-1.1 преобразуется в ab+0.19-1.1);

Делал её на C#. Теперь требуется сделать её на С. Вот моя программа на C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _270г
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string result = "";//В конце программы результат будет в этой строке

            Console.WriteLine("Введите строку: ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();

            int count = 0;//Это переменная нужна, для того чтобы считать символы
            int i = 0;
            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                if (c == ' ')
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка. Пробел не может быть первым значением");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if (char.IsDigit(c))//Проверям, является ли символ числом.
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count < 3)//Если число по порядку меньше трех, то добавляем символ в конечный результат.
                    {
                        result += c;
                    }//Если же число по порядку больше трех, то просто не добавляем этот символ         
                }
                else
                {
                    if (c == '.')
                    {
                        count = 0;//Если символ - это точка, то обнуляем счетчик.
                        result += c;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        result += c;//Если символ - это не число и не точка, то просто добавляем его в конечный результат.


                    }
                }


            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот попытка на С:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char str_[100];

void stroka(char *s, int l);

void main()
{   int a;
    gets(str_);
    a = strlen(str_);

    stroka(str_, a);
}

void stroka(char *str1, int a1)
{ int i, count = 0;
  char result;
    for (i = 0; i <= a1; i++)
        {
            if (str1[i] == ' ')
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        {
                            printf("Error. Spacebar can't be first digit ");
                        }
                    break;
                }
            if (isdigit(str1[i]))
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count < 3)
                        {
                            strcat(result,str1[i]);
                        }
                }
            else
                {
                    count = 0;
                    strcat(result,str1[i]);
                }
        }
    printf("%s", result);
}
```

Идея была в том, чтобы из массива строки скопировать необходимый символ в массив строки - результат. Но не вышло. Подскажите, как это реализовать, пожалуйста.

По-хорошему, ещё бы нужно, чтобы char не имел установленный размер 100, а увеличивался с пополнением, но с этим я попробую разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>     // strcat
#include <stdio.h>      // printf
#include <ctype.h>      // isdigit

char* get_string(char* str, int a);

int main()
{
    char str[256];
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    char* res = get_string(str, strlen(str));
    if (res)
    {
        printf("res=%s", res);
        free(res);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error. Spacebar can't be first digit.");
    }
    return 0;
}

char* get_string(char* str, int a)
{
    // стремитесь чтобы каждая функция, каждый модуль, каждая сущность
    // выполняла свое одно предназначение
    // эта функция находит нужную строку и возвращает, никаких сообщений
    // выводить не должна
    if (str[0] == ' ') // эту проверку необходимо вынести из цикла
    {                  // ранее на каждой итерации проводились
                       // абсолютно бесполезные проверки

        return NULL;    // первый пробел - ошибка
    }
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    unsigned index = 0;
    char* result = malloc(a); // выделяем память
    strchr(result, '\0');     // заполняем строку нулевыми символами
    for (; i <= a; ++i)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            ++count;        // если есть выбор, старайтесь предпочитать префиксный
                            // инкремент/декремент
            if (count < 3)
            {
                result[index] = str[i]; // strcat здесь не подойдет
                                        // т.к мы добавляем не строку а символ
                ++index;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
            result[index] = str[i];
            ++index;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Я делал проверку на пробел в цикле, потому что всё равно в цикле есть проверка, связанная с пробелом.

Теперь когда я делаю такую же проверку, начиная с 1 символа, чтобы не конфликтовать с тем условием, у меня условие выполняется, но вместо просто отсутствия символов после пробела возникает ошибки

Пока писал проверил, условие выполнено некорректно, поскольку цифры не должны быть записаны не только при условии что их больше 3х, но и при условии, что перед ними точка